# Magento 2.3 Static Content Deployment problem & missing css file

Tags: magento2, css, static-content

Running Magento 2.3 i noticed a problem with the static content being deployed, well, I believe it to be that anyway.

I was messing around with Varnish for a few days and had a nightmare getting it installed and running on the server, i decided that i should handle that problem another time so uninstalled it from the server but i am not sure if it has caused this reported problem.

I am using a 3rd party theme and naturally edited the themes css and files over time, when switching from developer mode to production the css breaks, in chrome console it would intermittently show that a custom.css is missing and now (today) the css and js being loaded have a strange URL, examples:

https://www.website.co.uk/pub/static/frontend/Codazon/fastest_hightech/en_GB/css/A.styles-m.css.pagespeed.cf.dZmez_UxRq.css

https://www.website.co.uk/pub/static/frontend/Codazon/fastest_hightech/en_GB/css/A.custom.css.pagespeed.cf.RRyT-2TOAp.css

I have tried the following:

1. Clearing cache and flush
2. bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy for different locals so en-GB en-US (i am using GB)
3. bin/magento setup:upgrade
4. setup:di:compile
5. copied a new .htaccess file into pub/static
6. checked mod_rewrite is on
7. httpd.confg file seems to be ok
8. removed everything from var/cache, var/page_cache, generated/code etc
9. export HTTPS=on and export HTTPS=off

I really need assistance on this urgently.

**Update:**
Tried reloading the site with: https://www.website.co.uk/?ModPagespeed=off which loaded the files without the Pagespeed rewrites, css is not loading still.

Switching back to developer mode brings the site back perfectly, obviously i cannot leave it on that mode but what is happening on switching?

Comment: I usually use all of this commands to clean cache
rm -rf pub/static/* 
rm -rf pub/static/frontend/* 
rm -rf var/cache/*
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/* 
rm -rf var/page_cache/*
rm -rf var/generation/*
After this add the deploy command
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB en_US

Comment: the * is the end of the line, you'll have to write those on separate lines

Comment: Made no difference unfortunately.

Comment: We had luck recompiling the css file and deploying that.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/152219)

Comment: if you have getting any solution for this then please post your answer to use for other.

Comment: I am stuck with same issue. I have tried to run all commands and also tried removing generated, pub/static etc. but no luck.